# Inserting values from a DataFrame into another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Ok, my real problem is bigger than this, but I have a simple working example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2, 1990], [4,1991], [5,1992]]), \
...                  index=[1,2,3], columns=['var', 'yr'])
>>> a
   var    yr
1    2  1990
2    4  1991
3    5  1992
>>> b = pd.DataFrame(index=a.index, columns=['new_var'])
>>> b
  new_var
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
>>> b[a.yr<1992].loc[:, 'new_var'] = a[a.yr<1992].loc[:, 'var']
>>> b
  new_var
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
```

I desire the following output:

```
>>> b
  new_var
1       2
2       4
3     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that filtering stuff, you're creating a copy of a slice, and thus it won't assign.

Do this instead:

`b.loc[a.yr<1992, 'new_var'] = a['var']`

Comment: This is a good answer!  However, the slice on `a` is unnecessary.  This will suffice `b.loc[a.yr<1992, 'new_var'] = a['var']`  `pandas` will handle the alignment for you.  +1 from me.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, Pandas seems to be pretty good at being reasonably concise.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `assign` + `query` to add intuitiveness

```
b.assign(new_var=a.query('yr < 1992')['var'])

   new_var
1      2.0
2      4.0
3      NaN
```

This returns the `dataframe` you'd want.  You'll have to assign it back to `b` if you want it to persist.

Comment: this is rather unusual use case for `assign` + `query` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU I'm always trying to push on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

yet another "creative" solution:

```
In [181]: b['new_var'] = np.where(a.yr < 1992, a['var'], b['new_var'])

In [182]: b
Out[182]:
  new_var
1       2
2       4
3     NaN
```